# AIR download prompt despite packaging with captive runtime

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I've recently encountered an issue where some android devices prompt user to download Adobe AIR despite packaging my app with captive runtime.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has any idea where to look for a solution?

To my knowledge this issue appears on Nexus 5 and LG G Flex models (probably more) and seems to be model specific - not an issue with particular devices.

The prompt requires the user to install Adobe AIR after every single update.

I have tried packaging with different versions of the SDK (19, 20 and 21) and to no effect - the issue persists on the same devices.

I'm using Flash Builder on a win 8 system and I am packaging via the windowed mode, not the command line.

I have several ANE's in my project, however none of them are currently linked nor are they packaged with the app.

This issue also affects my ability to publish to Amazon because of a custom prompt being displayed at the start of the application.

[solved]
It was an error on my part. A forgotten parameter in the build script that somehow slipped my eye, cause the devices I was testing on had AIR installed.

Comment: Try packaging with Air version 16. For my knowledge it does not happen on this SDK version.

Comment: It was an error on my part. Some merge left a "garbage" -target parameter that was used for testing and now it was overriding my choice.